# Maintaining Postgre connection while waiting for new tweet from Twitter Streaming API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io

I'm writing an app which catches tweets with a specific hashtag using the Twitter Streaming API. Each tweet caught must be inserted into my db and I need to perform another query to my db.

This is a not trending hashtag so let's assume there's around 400 tweets caught per hour. I currently open a new connection to my db each time I catch a tweet, process my queries then close the connection.

```
t.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    client.connect(function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error while connecting to PostgreSQL DB: ', error);
        }
        else {

            client.query('<MyQuery>',
                <MyParameters>,
                function (err, result) {

                    if (err) {
                        return console.error('error running query', err);
                    }
                    else {
                        client.query('<MyQuery>', function (err, result) {
                            client.end();

                            if (err) {
                                return console.error('error running count query', err);
                            }
                            else {

                                    io.emit('infos', {infos: {}});
                                }

                                return console.log('Tweet added');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
```

I post a tweet after running the server, the process is ok, but when posting another one something like 2 minutes later, I get the following output:

```
Tweet added
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:775:14)
```

**Can you tell me what's the best way to have my app always listening to a new tweet and insert it into the DB?** This way by creating a new connection each time (but I don't understand why it's crashing) or by opening a single connection at launch and maintain it opened during several weeks (I guess it's not the good option)?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up by instantiating a whole new client each time rather than calling `connect()` and `end()` methods.

```
t.on('tweet', function(tweet) {
    client = new pg.Client(conString);
```